# how to verify a hash in python?

Tags: python

I have a hashtable in python of strings. So, each entry is a string. The strings could possibly start with "/" which implies they are file names.
What would be a quick way to take a hashtable like this, and for each string in it that starts with a "/" verify whether the file exists?
If the file does not exist, then the

Comment: "If the file does not exist, then the"... you might want to edit your question and complete it.

Comment: -1: didn't copy and paste the entire homework assignment.

Comment: I'd say give him some time to complete his post.

Comment: @Skurmedel:  More than about a minute might mean they didn't care enough to proof-read their question.

Comment: @S.Lott: Quite possible.

Comment: @S.Lott: at least an answer was selected :D... The question is still FUBAR. I guess you were right.

Comment: @Skurmedel: I'm guessing they're in the same class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find if the string begins with a forward slash:

```
str.startswith('/')
```

or

```
str[0] == '/'
```

To find if a file is valid:

```
import os.path
os.path.exists(str)
```

You can loop through your hashtable using a for statement.  Putting it all together (assuming the potential paths are the values in the hashtable [called a dict in python]):

```
import os.path

for val in table.values():
    if val.startswith('/') and not os.path.exists(val):
        print "BAD FILE!!! ", val
```

Comment: ...and if you are going to manipulate the files, don't forget TOCTOU: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check-to-time-of-use :)